# How to pop a url segement in C#?

Tags: c#, url, segment

I was using this to obtain one of the url segments,

```
var hash = context.Request.Url.Segments[1];
```

but I need a method that would allow me to .Pop() the final segment off of the url. Pop doesn't seem to be a method available to Segments.. any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you seem to have your heart set on `Pop` for some reason:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

var stack = new Stack<string>(context.Request.Url);
var value = stack.Pop();
```

But you could just as easily use:

```
using System.Linq;

var value = context.Request.Url.Segments.Last();
```

Comment: This is not what he wanted. He wants a new url with the last segment removed.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
string.Join("/", url.Segments.Take(url.Segments.Count-1).ToArray())
```

This might get you started.